# putting selected array in to a listbox

Tags: c#

I would like to Implement the following feature: when a user selects a movie from the dropdownlist and clicks on the ‘Add to cart’ button, the movie is then added into the list box below.

```
protected void addImageButton_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
    string[] moviesArrayString = new string[10];

    moviesArrayString[1] = "Badboy 2";
    moviesArrayString[2] = "BadBoy 3";
    moviesArrayString[3] = "The Godfather";
    moviesArrayString[4] = "Inception";
    moviesArrayString[5] = "The Shawshank Redemtion";
    moviesArrayString[6] = "Star Wars";
    moviesArrayString[7] = "The Metrix";
    moviesArrayString[8] = "King Kong";
    moviesArrayString[9] = "Point Break";
    moviesArrayString[10] = "Top Gun";


    cartListBox.Items.AddRange(moviesArrayString);
}
```

It give me some error and I couldn't figure out how to do so? 
error is index was outside the bound of arrays?

Comment: You need to be a little more descriptive in your description of "some error" that's a little vague.

Comment: Are you use multiselect dropDownList ryt ?

Answer (score 3):

Arrays in C# are zero-based. Use the indexes from 0 to 9:

```
protected void addImageButton_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
    string[] moviesArrayString = new string[10];

    moviesArrayString[0] = "Badboy 2";
    moviesArrayString[1] = "BadBoy 3";
    moviesArrayString[2] = "The Godfather";
    moviesArrayString[3] = "Inception";
    moviesArrayString[4] = "The Shawshank Redemtion";
    moviesArrayString[5] = "Star Wars";
    moviesArrayString[6] = "The Metrix";
    moviesArrayString[7] = "King Kong";
    moviesArrayString[8] = "Point Break";
    moviesArrayString[9] = "Top Gun";

    cartListBox.Items.AddRange(moviesArrayString);
}
```

Alternatively, you can use:

```
string[] moviesArrayString =
{
    "Badboy 2", "BadBoy 3", "The Godfather", "Inception",
    "The Shawshank Redemtion", "Star Wars", "The Matrix", "King Kong", "Point Break", "Top Gun"
};
```

Comment: The index starts at zero meaning moviesArrayString[0] to moviesArrayString[9]. You're referencing moviesArrayString[10] in your code, that element does not exist. Hence you get the out-of-bound exception.

Comment: What does this question have to do with the array indexes you're using?

Answer (score 0):

Just set the `DataSource` instead of adding item into listBox......

```
string[] moviesArrayString =
{
    "Badboy 2", "BadBoy 3", "The Godfather", "Inception",
    "The Shawshank Redemtion", "Star Wars", "The Matrix", "King Kong", "Point Break", "Top Gun"
};

 listBox1.DataSource = moviesArrayString;
```

Answer (score -1):

Use List<> or ArrayList in the place of string[].

For Example:

```
ArrayList lst=new ArrayList();
lst.Add("badboy2");
lst.Add("badbo32");
lst.Add("badb2");
lst.Add("bboy2");
lst.Add("bad2");
foreach(string str in lst)
{
cartListBox.Items.Add(str);
}
```